# Where can I get brush stroke caligraphy fonts for traditional characters?

Tags: traditional-characters, software, fonts

I need to print out characters written with obvious brush strokes, such as semi-cursive script (行書). Are there computer fonts (e.g. TrueType, OpenType) available for this purpose? The font must support traditional characters, and should preferably be free to use.

Comment: good things are usually not free

Comment: Related question at Graphic Design: [Where to find a handwritten font with English and Chinese?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/7610)

Answer (score 1):

You can try searching a site like http://www.fonts.net.cn/ with queries such as [繁行](http://www.fonts.net.cn/font-search-result-417842298549-1.html).

Unfortunately, a lot of these just map simplified [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) to traditional [glyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) and don't even contain mappings for the corresponding traditional code points. But it looks like at least some of them work with traditional code points, such as [王漢宗中行書繁](http://www.fonts.net.cn/font-35989421872.html).